# return from custom function doesn't affect the validation in joi

Tags: javascript, joi

I using `custom` function in `Joi`.

When I return `true` the validation pass
But when I return `false` the validation also pass

Why? I do something wrong here? any idea how to make it work?

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-bush-qfi7b?file=/src/index.ts)

```
import * as Joi from "joi";

console.clear();

const schema = Joi.object({
  foo: Joi.string().custom((x, y) => {
    console.log("in foo");
    return false;
  })
});

schema
  .validateAsync({ foo: "x" })
  .then((x) => {
    console.log({ x });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log({ err });
  });
```

Comment: I believe you have to `throw` an error if the validation shouldn't pass.

Comment: @goto1 is right, you need to throw a `new Error()` and then you will be able to access the error details in your `catch` through `err.details[0]`.